# How does go successfully get a package with broken link?

Tags: go, github, command-line-interface

I ran command `go get github.com/docker/docker/client` in my terminal and it successfully downloaded a specific package to my $GOPATH. But if i try to use this link in a browser, it appears broken, GitHub gives 404. Can you please explain what is going on? Why the operation is successful while the link is broken?

Comment: `github.com/docker/docker/client` is an import path. It isn't a url, and isn't meant to point to a web page.

Comment: @JimB ok. but what structure does this import path have?

Comment: Read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), specifically the "Remote Packages" section.

Comment: I found this in `go help importpath`: `import "github.com/user/project/sub/directory"`. So it means that there must be repository called "docker" by user with the same name. But I don't see such repo at GitHub

Comment: Read [Remote import paths](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths) for a description of how import paths are resolved to a remote repository.

Comment: @Azatik1000 I have explained in my answer why you don't see that URL on GitHub.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Yes, I have explained in my answer *why* GitHub redirects to moby/moby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package registry [pkg.go.dev](https://pkg.go.dev/) does mention for [`pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client?tab=overview) that the repository is:

- https://github.com/docker/docker which redirect to `moby/moby`, since the repo [was renamed in April 2017](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/04/21/docker_renames_open_source_code_moby/), and GitHub will redirect automatically to the renamed one.
- https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/v1.13.1/client which does redirect to an existing URL for Go to clone.

See more at [PackagePublishing](http://PackagePublishing).

Comment: Note: there is a project to rename moby/moby back to docker/docker (https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40222), but it is still in discussion for now.

Answer (score 1):

It's because GitHub inserts `tree/master/` in [the url](https://github.com/moby/moby/tree/master/client) when going to a subfolder in a repository. When you download it using go get, you'll get the normal directory structure that has a `client` directory at the top level

Comment: Yes, I mentioned in my answer https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/v1.13.1/client which redirects to https://github.com/moby/moby/tree/v1.13.1/client